# Pyaudio be used in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have installed pyaudio in colab but when I import pyaudio I get an error, I tried using the command:

!pip install pipwin

!pipwin install pyaudio

Answer (score 0):

It was mentioned in [PyAudio](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/) that you need to install it on `GNU/Linux` with `sudo apt install python3-pyaudio`.

So to install PyAudio you need to install on google colab with `!sudo apt install python3-pyaudio`